# Can you modify this theorem from measure theory?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-limit-theorems

I am looking at the following theorem (16) on pg. 22. of this [paper](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2461571):

"Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a finite measure space, $f$ a non-negative, real-valued measurable function, and $\varphi:[0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ a continuously differentiable and monotonically increasing function with $\varphi(0)=0$. Then

\begin{equation}
 \int \varphi \circ f  \, d\mu \; = \; \int \limits_{0}^{\infty} \varphi'(x) \, \mu(f>x) \, dx. \label{equ_mt}
\end{equation}
"

I currently have an integral of this form where $\varphi$ is either positive and monotone decreasing, or negative and monotone increasing. So $\varphi$ in my case fulfills either only one of the two conditions for the above theorem.

Can someone provide a modified version of the above theorem, where $\varphi$ is positive and monotone decreasing, or negative and monotone increasing (e.g. maybe set "$f<x$" in the right part of the equation)?

Comment: If $\phi$ is negative, monotone increasing, and bounded below, then $\phi(0)$ is the greatest lower bound, so replace $\phi$ by
$$
\phi - \phi(0),
$$
which is by construction nonnegative, monotone increasing, and equals $0$ at $x=0$.

But if your original (negative and increasing) $\phi$ is not bounded below, e.g. $\phi(x) = - 1/x$, I don't know how to handle the problem.

Comment: @avs Thank you very much for your suggestion. Unfortunately I have indeed $\varphi$ unbounded from below.

Comment: In that case, $\phi$ cannot be continuous at $x=0$.  Still, depending on what you are trying to do, you might get somewhere by considering, instead of $[0, +\infty[$, the subdomains of the form $[\epsilon, +\infty[$, where $\epsilon > 0$ is sufficiently small, yet is a point of continuity for $\phi$.

Another approach, instead of truncating the domains, is to truncate $\phi$ itself: replace it by
$$
\max \{ \phi, - M \},
$$
where $M$ is very large.  I might know more if I knew your goals.

Comment: @avs Thank you for your suggestion. Indeed in my example I consider a subdomain $[\epsilon,\infty]$. If I truncate $\varphi$ then it is no longer monotone, which is required by the theorem. My goal is to apply the above theorem for $\varphi$ of the form $\varphi=1/U(x)$ with $U'(x)>0$.

Comment: It can be truncated so as to be strictly increasing (I am realizing now that's what you wanted): $\max{\phi, -M + cx}$, where $c$ is positive.  It can then fail to be continuously differentiable at one point, but the cusp can be smoothed.